# Replace this lambda with a method reference

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube, java-stream

I have the following code. Sonar is complaining replace this lambda with a method reference.

```
Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(100).map(i -> Integer.toString(i));
```

If I replace it with it code below, it does not compile with compilation error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Stream<Object>` to `<unknown>`.

```
Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(100).map(Integer::toString);
```

How is `Integer::toString` converting `Stream<Object>` to `<unknown>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't put `Integer::toString` because `Integer` has two implementations that fit to functional interface `Function<Integer, String>`, but you can use `String::valueOf` instead:

```
Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
        .limit(100)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: *You can't put `Integer::toString` because it accepts `int` and your case you have `Integer` use.* That's not correct. Lambdas can implicitly box and unbox.

Comment: @shmosel then why does it `IntStream.range(1, 100).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())` work?

Comment: Because the `int` overload is more appropriate for a primitive stream.

Comment: @shmosel yes, you are right about _Lambdas can implicitly box and unbox_

Answer (score 9):

It's ambiguous because the [static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-) and [non-static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-) `toString()` methods are both compatible with the functional signature `Integer -> String`. You can use `String::valueOf` instead.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @shmosel already replacing the lambda with a method reference will lead to ambiguity as there's two `toString` method of the signarure:

- [`String toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString--)
- [`static String toString(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-)

because the call to `Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)` returns a `Stream<Integer>` when you call `map` with the method reference `Integer::toString` the compiler is not sure whether you meant to do `Integer.toString(i)` or `i.toString()` hence the compilation error.

So here are other options to what's already been provided:

instead of `Stream.iterate` you can use `IntStream.iterate` then call `mapToObj`:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1) // IntStream
         .limit(100) // IntStream
         .mapToObj(Integer::toString); // i1 -> Integer.toString(i1)
```

Another thing suggested by `intelliJ` is that you can actually do:

```
Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1) // Stream<Integer>
      .limit(100) // Stream<Integer>
      .map(Object::toString); // integer -> integer.toString()
```

where `Object::toString` is equivalent to the lambda `integer -> integer.toString()`

---

on another note, it's interesting that Sonar is suggesting to replace the lambda with a method reference in the code you've shown. intelliJ IDEA was smart enough not to suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `IntStream` is better for your code:

```
List<String> numbers = IntStream.range(0, 100)
                                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or for your example do use `String.valueOf` to conver `int -> String`:

```
List<String> numbers = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
                             .limit(100)
                             .map(String::valueOf)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```